# ElephantBird ERROR 1070: --- > class not getting read

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-pig, elephantbird

My problem is similar to this unanswered question :

> [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140344/elephantbird-dependency-jars][1]

i have registered all jars mandatory for elephantbird to function.

```
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1
REGISTER '/MyJARS/json-simple-1.1.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-pig-4.1.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-core-4.10.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/google-collections-1.0.jar';
```

> following links tell me these info : 
>   1 :
>   [Loading data from HDFS does not work with Elephantbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17879259/loading-data-from-hdfs-does-not-work-with-elephantbird?rq=1)
>
> 2 :
>   [how to load twitter data from hdfs using pig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557555/how-to-load-twitter-data-from-hdfs-using-pig)

```
My current versions :
Hadoop: Hadoop 2.6.0-cdh5.7.3
Pig: Apache Pig version 0.12.0-cdh5.7.3 (rexported)
```

I receive following error :

> ERROR 1070: Could not resolve
>   com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader using imports: [,
>   java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]

Any help is appreciated , I tried almost all possible solutions across web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an versioning  problem. After trying many jars from [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter.elephantbird/elephant-bird-core) link , it finally worked with elephant-bird-pig-4.14.jar

```
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-hadoop-compat-4.1
REGISTER '/MyJARS/json-simple-1.1.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-pig-4.14.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/elephant-bird-core-4.10.jar';
REGISTER '/MyJARS/google-collections-1.0.jar';
```