# Pig query for set operation A-B

Tags: apache-pig

I have the following requirement -

I have a big file containing rows of data in json format -

```
{
    "_length": "88",
    "_id" : "1",
    "_store": {
        "meta": {
            "value": {
                "uid": "sam",
            }
        }
    }
}
{
    "_length": "22",
    "_id" : "2",
    "_store": {
        "meta": {
            "value": {
                "uid": "uncle",
            }
        }
    }
}
```

....

I have another file containing the following -

```
 {
      "uid" : "sam",
      "zid" : "121212121"
  }
  {
      "uid" : "aborted",
      "zid" : "9989821"
  }
```

....

Now I need to generate a new file from the 1st file containing all the records
having udi's not in the 2nd file.

I am new to Pig and wanted to know what sort of JOIN or SET operation is supported.

Comment: See here http://datafu.incubator.apache.org/docs/datafu/guide/set-operations.html

Answer (score 0):

I think elephantbird can help you out here. I never tried such stuffs but as yours is nested json   , you can read 2 files into 2 variable using elephant bird , and then perhaps join and achieve your target.

These are couple of links which will help you with starting with elephantbird .

> [ElephantBird ERROR 1070: --- > class not getting read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42369307/elephantbird-error-1070-class-not-getting-read)
>
> https://github.com/twitter/elephant-bird

Comment: I am already using elephant bird and figured out that i need to use 2 'replicated' JOINS with FILTERs to achieve this case.

Comment: would you mind posting the code , may be it will be helpful for any in future. !

Answer (score 0):

The following are the sample files and respective intermediate and final results -

```
cat ids_test.json
{"A":"a1","B":"a2"}

cat part-test
{"content":"both_A_a1_B_a2","meta":{"A":"a1","B":"a2"}}
{"content":"only_B_a2","meta":{"A":"","B":"a2"}}
{"content":"only_A_a1","meta":{"A":"a1","B":""}}
{"content":"both_A_b1_B_b2","meta":{"A":"b1","B":"b2"}}
{"content":"only_A_c1","meta":{"A":"c1","B":""}}

cat /tmp/j1/part-m-00000
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=a1}","content":"both_A_a1_B_a2"},"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=a1}","content":"only_A_a1"},"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/j1_filter/part-m-00000
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"ids::json":null}
{"user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/j2/part-m-00000
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=a2, A=}","content":"only_B_a2"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":{"B":"a2","A":"a1"}}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":null}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"},"J1_FILTER::ids::json":null,"ids::json":null}

cat /tmp/results/part-m-00000
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=b2, A=b1}","content":"both_A_b1_B_b2"}}
{"J1_FILTER::user_data::json":{"meta":"{B=, A=c1}","content":"only_A_c1"}}
```

The following is the script -

```
user_data = LOAD 'part-test' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
ids = LOAD 'ids_test.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (json:map[]);
J1 = JOIN user_data BY json#'meta'#'A' LEFT OUTER, ids BY json#'A' USING 'replicated';

rmf /tmp/j1
store J1 into '/tmp/j1' USING JsonStorage;

J1_FILTER = FILTER J1 BY ids::json is null;

rmf /tmp/j1_filter
store J1_FILTER into '/tmp/j1_filter' USING JsonStorage;

J2 = JOIN J1_FILTER BY user_data::json#'meta'#'B' left outer, ids BY json#'B' USING 'replicated';

rmf /tmp/j2
store J2 into '/tmp/j2' USING JsonStorage;

J2_FILTER = FILTER J2 BY ids::json is null;

RESULTS = FOREACH J2_FILTER GENERATE J1_FILTER::user_data::json;
--filtered_ids = FOREACH user_data_MINUS_ids GENERATE user_data AS data;
--DUMP filtered_ids;
rmf /tmp/results
store RESULTS into '/tmp/results' USING JsonStorage;
```